# Double Integrating Gaussian Noise

Tags: noise, gaussian, integration

My question has to do with integrating gaussian noise.

Let us assume we have samples of discrete gaussian white noise  with mean $\mu = 0$ and variance $\sigma_{th}^2$. These noise samples are passed through the system shown in the Figure (a cascade of two integrators with outputs $y_1[n]$ and $y_2[n]$, respectively).
[image]

What will be the mean and variance of $y_1$ and $y_2$ (let us say after $N$ cycles)?

Comment: The output of your summer is a single random variable. It is a Gaussian random variable, and you don't need the Central Limit Theorem to assert this: the sum of independent Gaussian random variables is Gaussian: no asymptotics or limits needed.The rest of your question makes no sense because the output of the first summer **is not a random process or white noise** and so there is nothing except one random variable to pass on to the next summer.

Comment: I think perhaps a simpler way to the question is this - "IF white gaussian noise is passed through two integrators, what will the output of the second integrator look like?" 
I strongly suspect this has something to do with the Wiener Process, but I cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: Can you answer the question for a _non-random_ sequence first? Go on! Take your best shot at **writing down** in mathematical notation and no verbal gobbledygook the value of the output of the first integrator at time $t=1$? the output of the second integrator at time $t=1$? Now, up the ante and try to do the same for $t=2$ and possibly even for $t=3$. If you cannot do these calculations by yourself, then _any_ answer that can be given, no matter how ridiculous, will suffice for your needs since you cannot tell the difference between shinola.

Comment: In the case of a deterministic sequence, the outputs can easily be determined. assuming that x[n]
is the sequence of inputs to the first integrator.At time t=0, both the integrators will have zero outputs (I am assuming delaying integrators$\frac{z−1}{1−z^{−1}}$). At $t=1$, integrator 1($y1$) will output $y1=x[0]$, integrator 2 ($y2=0$). At $t=2$,  $y1=x[0]+x[1],y2=x[0]$. At $t=3$, $y1=x[0]+x[1]+x[2], y2=2×x[0]+x[1]$, so on and so forth.

Comment: Good! Now consider _editing_ your _question_ because it mentions only a $y$, not a $y_1$ (or $y_2$ for that matter). How does the _time index_ come into play? How can you tell the difference between $y1 = x[0]+x[1]$ and $y1 = x[0]+x[1]+x[2]$?? and how are these things related to the $y$ in your displayed equation?

Comment: I have modified the question, I hope it is a bit clearer now. I have a few remarks, and I was hoping you could comment on whether I am right or not?  **1)** Since $x[n]$ is comprised of samples of white noise, it is equivalent to a random variable with the same statistics (assume wide sense stationarity for this?) **2)** The means of both $y_1[n]$ and $y_2[n]$ are zero (linear sytems cannot create any new frequency content). **3)** The variance of $y_1[n]$, will be $n \times \sigma_{th}^2$ (sum of random variables?), and hence  $N \times \sigma_{th}^2$, after $N$ cycles.

Comment: The question is much clearer and you have correctly figured out that $y_1[n] \sim \mathcal N(0,n\sigma^2)$, but as with $y_1[n]$, finding the distribution of $y_2[n]$ requires getting rid of those $z$-transforms and writing $y_2[n]$ as a weighted sum (or linear combination) of $x[0],x]1],x[2],\ldots$ and then using the result that a weighted sum of independent Gaussian random variables is $\mathcal N\left(\sum a_i\mu_i,\sum a_i^2\sigma_i^2\right)$. You began doing the needed calculations in response to an earlier comment of mine.

Comment: Ok, here we go. The second integrator output at the end of $N$ cycles (starting from $n=0$ to $n=N-1$) can be expressed as $y_2[N-1]=(N-2)x[0] + (N-3)x[1] + (N-4)x[2]...+x[N-3]$. Taking the variance of both sides, we obtain
$\sigma_{y_2}^2=\sigma_{th}^2(1+2^2+3^2+...(N-2)^2)=\sigma_{th}^2\frac{(N-2)(N-1)(2N-3)}{6}\approx \sigma_{th}^2\frac{N^3}{3} (N>>1)$. Does that look right?

Comment: Looks OK. Now please write up your work neatly and post it as an answer to your own question so that it does not remain as an unanswered question on this site.

Comment: Thank you Dilip for all your help. I have marked the question as answered now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Dilip, I managed to figure out the answer to the question.
$y_1[n]$ will  be a normal random variable, with its variance given by the following equation:

\begin{equation}
\sigma_{y_1}^2=N\sigma_{th}^2
\end{equation}

This can be explained by using the fact that the variances will just add up. The mean will stay zero.$\\$
A similar approach can be used to find the variance of $y_2[n]$ ($\sigma_{y_2}$), which begins by writing the equation for $y_2[N-1]$ ($y_2[n]$ after $N$ cycles):

\begin{equation}
y_2[N-1]=(N-2)x[0] + (N-3)x[1] + (N-4)x[2]...+x[N-3]
\end{equation}

Taking variances on both sides:

\begin{equation}
\sigma_{y_2}^2=\sigma_{th}^2(1+2^2+3^2+...(N-2)^2)=\sigma_{th}^2\frac{(N-2)(N-1‌​)(2N-3)}{6}\approx \sigma_{th}^2\frac{N^3}{3} (N>>1)
\end{equation}

Again, the mean will stay zero.